# Memory leak in Pandas.groupby.apply()?

Tags: python, memory-leaks, pandas

I'm currently using Pandas for a project with csv source files of around 600mb. During the analysis I am reading in the csv to a dataframe, grouping on some column and applying a simple function to the grouped dataframe. I noticed that I was going into Swap Memory during this process and so carried out a basic test:

I first created a fairly large dataframe in the shell:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3000000, 3),index=range(3000000),columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

I defined a pointless function called do_nothing():

```
def do_nothing(group):
    return group
```

And ran the following command:

```
df = df.groupby('a').apply(do_nothing)
```

My system has 16gb of RAM and is running Debian (Mint). After creating the dataframe I was using ~600mb of RAM. As soon as the apply method began to execute, that value started to soar. It steadily climbed up to around 7gb(!) before finishing the command and settling back down to 5.4gb (while the shell was still active). The problem is, my work requires doing more than the 'do_nothing' method and as such while executing the real program, I cap my 16gb of RAM and start swapping, making the program unusable. Is this intended? I can't see why Pandas should need 7gb of RAM to effectively 'do_nothing', even if it has to store the grouped object.

Any ideas on what's causing this/how to fix it?

Cheers,

.P

Comment: This doesn't necessarily have to be a memory leak; it could just be an algorithm that uses a huge amount of temporary storage and properly releases it all at the end. (Python usually doesn't release memory back to the OS. But even if it did, that wouldn't help you, because it's peak usage you're concerned with.)

Comment: Good point. I can't imagine what algorithm Pandas could be employing to require this much temporary storage though. I guess I need to find a Pandas expert who can suggest a work around, if it is indeed intended and just a by product of the method.

Comment: That example is somewhat pathological.  The groupby creates a separate group for each distinct value.  Since you generated the values as random floats, it's likely that they are all distinct, which means there are 3 million groups.  Each group passed to your `do_nothing` is a DataFrame, so you are creating 3 million DataFrames (which `apply` then has to aggregate into a single result).  Even if each has only one row, this is a lot of overhead.  It might be more illuminating to create an exmaple whose "groupiness" (i.e., number of distinct groups) is more in line with your actual data.

Comment: I agree, it was a tad sadistic. So you are saying that a dataframe containing 3 columns and 2 rows is less than twice the size of a dataframe with 3 columns and 1 row? That may well be the case (I'm not sure how the backend of Pandas does things to be quite honest). The data in my project has an average 'groupiness' of around 3-5 rows per group, coming from a dataframe with ~2.5mil rows. So while I agree that using a coarser grouping might help, it isn't really feasible in this particular project.

Comment: @user3908739: Well, yes.  DataFrames are Python objects and have overhead associated with them; they can't just store the raw bytes of their data without any wrapping.  So lots of tiny DataFrames is going to take more memory than a few large ones.  That said, the memory usage you report does seem pretty high.  I'm not an expert on pandas internals either, though, so maybe if one comes along you can get more insight into how to manage this.  Out of curiosity, what happens if you make your `do_nothing` return, say, 1 instead of `group`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using 0.14.1, I don't think their is a memory leak (1/3 size of your frame).

```
In [79]: df = DataFrame(np.random.randn(100000,3))

In [77]: %memit -r 3 df.groupby(df.index).apply(lambda x: x)
maximum of 3: 1365.652344 MB per loop

In [78]: %memit -r 10 df.groupby(df.index).apply(lambda x: x)
maximum of 10: 1365.683594 MB per loop
```

Two general comments on how to approach a problem like this:

1) use the cython level function if at all possible, will be MUCH faster, and will use much less memory. IOW, it almost always worth it to decouple a groupby expression and void using function (if possible, somethings are just too complicated, but that's the point, you want to break things down). e.g.

Instead of:

```
df.groupby(...).apply(lambda x: x.sum() / x.mean())
```

It is MUCH better to do:

```
g = df.groupby(...)
g.sum() / g.mean()
```

2) You can easily 'control' the groupby by doing your aggregation manually (additionally this will allow periodic output and garbage collection if needed).

```
results = []
for i, (g, grp) in enumerate(df.groupby(....)):

    if i % 500 == 0:
        print "checkpoint: %s" % i
        gc.collect()


    results.append(func(g,grp))

# final result
pd.concate(results)
```

Comment: That running `gc.collect()` on every n hundred rows using an iteration seems like it shouldn't be so much cheaper on memory than `.apply()`, but nonetheless, this approach made a huge difference for me. It was the only way I could get pandas to work on large dataframes without the process being killed for using too much RAM.

See also: https://ys-l.github.io/posts/2015/08/28/how-not-to-use-pandas-apply/

Comment: Do you mean concat or concate?

Comment: The result object is Series, and not Dataframe

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
result_df = None
        for i, (account_id, grp) in enumerate(grouped_df):
            grp.name = account_id
            if i % 500 == 0:
                print(f"\rStep {i}", end="", flush=True)
                gc.collect()

            series = partial_func(grp)
            if (
                series is not None
            ):  
                dataframed = series.to_frame().transpose()

                if result_df is None:
                    result_df = dataframed
                else:
                    result_df.append(dataframed)

            else:
                print("Cleaning dropped row.")

       
        grouped_df = result_df
        del result_df
        gc.collect()
```