# Alternative to 'Apply' on Pandas GroupBy Object

Tags: python, pandas

So I have the following:

```
timeDiffFunc = lambda x: x['CP_EX_DT'] - x['CP_EX_DT'].shift(1)
exTimeDiff = assetGrp.apply(timeDiffFunc).fillna(0).reset_index(level=1)
```

But this uses so much memory that my system crashes (similar to the issue seen here: [Memory leak in Pandas.groupby.apply()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25130839/memory-leak-in-pandas-groupby-apply))

My question is, how can I convert this to code that does not use the apply function? I tried variations of:

```
for i, (name,grp) in enumerate(assetGrp):
  grp = grp['CP_EX_DT'] - grp['CP_EX_DT'].shift(1)
exTimeDiff = assetGrp.fillna(0).reset_index(level=1)
```

but always received an error like: `NotImplementedError: Index._join_level on non-unique index is not implemented` when trying to merge the result back into the dataframe.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Now I am just curious, but what happens if you replace the apply function by just `.diff()` ? like assetGrp.diff()

Comment: A cutout of your data and what you want the output to look like would help. Take the first 5 rows, apply your operation, and paste your output.

Answer (score 0):

As per Uvar's comment above, assetGrp.diff() did the same thing with a much lower memory overhead.